# Setting up razer tartarus for a World of Warcraft warlock

Tags: world-of-warcraft, razer-synapse

Used a G13 for many years.  It was the best -- the most buttons on the finger tips and two easily accessible modifier buttons.

The G13 finally broke beyond repair, and so I'm transitioning to the Razer Tartarus.  I've managed to solve most of the keybinding issues, but I'm really struggling to put the tab in a place that's natural.

The Razer Tartarus looks like this.  Key 06 is bound to `<tab>`, key 11 is bound to `<alt>`, and the thumb button is bound to `<ctrl>`.

[image]

And here's what my keybindings look like.  Key 01 is bound to auto-run, but the rest are pretty well-explained by the picture.

[image]

The problem is that tab targeting is very awkward.  Anyone who plays a dot class knows that you spend a lot of time tab targeting.  However, when I move my pinky up to hit tab, I find that my ring, middle, and pointer finger tend to creep up too.  This makes it difficult to make sure those three hit the intended buttons when it comes time.

Thoughts I've had are as follows:

- Bind  and + to buttons on the mouse and use that.  While I've got tons of buttons, I find the mouse awkward.  So, I'm trying to avoid it.
- Move all of the instant cast/multi-target dots to the 2nd row (counting from the top), and move all of the single-target dots/nukes to the third row.  At least then, when I'm in "dot it all" mode, everything I need is on the same row, lessening finger confusion.

Anyone have other ideas?  Stackexchange seems to be one of the best places to document approaches like this.  At least, it's way better than writing a random blog post that no one would ever be able to use as a reference.

W.r.t. the potential for "too subjective" moderation closures:  I would argue that there *is* a "best and most optimal" way to set this all up.  E.g. one person might have smaller hands, but having a closer reach to something is also good for someone with larger hands.  Another useful illustration is that a rogue might prefer to not use vanish in combat, so it wouldn't need to be on their button/combo that's most easily pressed.  However, the best rogues in the world *would* use vanish in combat, and so they would want it easily accessed.  This question seeks the answer for this min/maxed scenario.  Of course the min/max will change as abilities get tuned, but that's a traditional problem that we already deal with.  People will have different approaches, but the point is that these questions do actually have an *optimal* solution (or, at least, just handful of them).

Comment: The answer would be subjective to the player so it wouldn't be a "this is the right answer for everyone" and will likely be closed. Everyone has different hand sizes so what is easy to reach for you or seems logical to you, won't work for anyone else. I think you'd be better asking in the wow or razer sub-reddits. PS. yay upgrades, I had to recently upgrade to the same model from a Belkin n52te myself. I've had some challenges myself adjusting muscle memory. The nice thing is that the Synapse software will let you rebind until your hand feels comfortable with your actions.

Comment: Thanks for being supportive even though it's not all great opinion Sorean :).  I hope it stays open, as reddit isn't as good of a platform for this type of discussion.  I'd forgotten about my old belkin n52!  Wow, that was awhile ago.  I'm slowly getting used to having fewer keys, though, I'm still struggling with tab and alt both wanting to be on the 11 key.  Having a second thumb modifier that's accessible would have solved this problem, but oh well.  At least the mechanical switches on the razer are way better and the colors are nice.  The g13's buttons are kind of annoying to push now.

Comment: @Sorean is right though, this site is tailored for questions that have a concrete right answer, and not an opinion based one. I'm curious as to why you think Reddit wouldn't be as good of a platform? There are plenty of opinion based posts on there, so I honestly think you'd have better luck there.